# Is the cotangent complex sensitive to truncation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry, cotangent-complex

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$If $V$ is a dg vector space (in positive degrees), we can view it as a derived scheme $V = \Sym V^*$. It has (co)tangent complex $V$ (and $V^*$).  What is the relation of this to the cotangent complex of $H^0(V)$?

---

I'm not sure what the correct statement is to make, so I will include an example to indicate the sort of thing I'm trying to understand. Take
$$\Spec \mathbf{C}[x,y]/xy.$$
which has $\mathbf{C}[x,y]/xy=H^0(\mathbf{C}[xy]\to\mathbf{C}[x]\oplus\mathbf{C}[y])$. Its tangent complex is $V=\mathcal{O}^2\xrightarrow{(x,y)}\mathcal{O}$ (concentrated in degrees 0, 1), which has $\Sym V^*=(\mathbf{C}[xy]\to\mathbf{C}[x]\oplus\mathbf{C}[y])$.

I've written in terms of dg vector spaces for simplicitly, the answer should of course work for perfect complexes.

Comment: Your example isn't of the form Sym$V^*$, because the generator in degree $-1$ isn't mapping to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear combination of $x,y$. In general, the cotangent complex of a derived scheme doesn't tell you much about the higher terms of the cotangent complex of its truncation.